# Azure DevOps Pipeline Migrations SQL not found

Tags: sql-server, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, entity-framework-migrations

I am building my Release Pipeline which contains a stage to deploy the migrations to my SQL Server Database on my own Server. The build pipeline produces the `.sql` script and publishes it into the migrations folder

[image]

Inside the release pipeline, I added a Task named `SQL Server database deploy` and set the path to the `.sql` file

[image]

Now if I run that pipeline, it runs into an error

`[error]No files were found to deploy with search pattern D:\a\r1\a/drop/migrations/TimeServiceDataContext.sql`

So there must be a wrong path provided, but I can't find out, which might be the correct one.

Here is the debug output

```
2020-06-14T21:00:46.9140268Z ##[debug]Evaluating condition for step: 'Deploy using : sqlQuery'
2020-06-14T21:00:46.9142671Z ##[debug]Evaluating: succeeded()
2020-06-14T21:00:46.9143229Z ##[debug]Evaluating succeeded:
2020-06-14T21:00:46.9144608Z ##[debug]=> True
2020-06-14T21:00:46.9145556Z ##[debug]Result: True
2020-06-14T21:00:46.9146106Z ##[section]Starting: Deploy using : sqlQuery
2020-06-14T21:00:46.9277557Z ==============================================================================
2020-06-14T21:00:46.9277903Z Task         : SQL Server database deploy
2020-06-14T21:00:46.9278185Z Description  : Deploy a SQL Server database using DACPAC or SQL scripts
2020-06-14T21:00:46.9278427Z Version      : 0.3.23
2020-06-14T21:00:46.9278632Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-06-14T21:00:46.9278995Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/sql-dacpac-deployment-on-machine-group
2020-06-14T21:00:46.9279376Z ==============================================================================
2020-06-14T21:00:48.0530812Z ##[debug]VstsTaskSdk 0.8.2 commit 
2020-06-14T21:00:48.2649638Z ##[debug]Entering D:\a\_tasks\SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroup_4b506f7f-720f-47bb-bf21-029bac6a690d\0.3.23\Main.ps1.
2020-06-14T21:00:48.2752917Z ##[debug]Loading resource strings from: D:\a\_tasks\SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroup_4b506f7f-720f-47bb-bf21-029bac6a690d\0.3.23\Task.json
2020-06-14T21:00:48.3003693Z ##[debug]Loaded 6 strings.
2020-06-14T21:00:48.3288927Z ##[debug]SYSTEM_CULTURE: 'en-US'
2020-06-14T21:00:48.3289509Z ##[debug]Loading resource strings from: D:\a\_tasks\SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroup_4b506f7f-720f-47bb-bf21-029bac6a690d\0.3.23\Strings\resources.resjson\en-US\resources.resjson
2020-06-14T21:00:48.3331827Z ##[debug]Loaded 6 strings.
2020-06-14T21:00:48.3607995Z ##[debug]INPUT_TASKTYPE: 'sqlQuery'
2020-06-14T21:00:48.3663637Z ##[debug]INPUT_DACPACFILE: 'D:\a\r1\a'
2020-06-14T21:00:48.3665646Z ##[debug]INPUT_SQLFILE: 'D:\a\r1\a/drop/migrations/TimeServiceDataContext.sql'
2020-06-14T21:00:48.3680833Z ##[debug]INPUT_EXECUTEINTRANSACTION: 'false'
2020-06-14T21:00:48.3721277Z ##[debug] Converted to bool: False
2020-06-14T21:00:48.3755339Z ##[debug]INPUT_EXCLUSIVELOCK: 'false'
2020-06-14T21:00:48.3778148Z ##[debug] Converted to bool: False
2020-06-14T21:00:48.3809928Z ##[debug]INPUT_APPLOCKNAME (empty)
2020-06-14T21:00:48.3882461Z ##[debug]INPUT_INLINESQL (empty)
2020-06-14T21:00:48.3919370Z ##[debug]INPUT_TARGETMETHOD: 'server'
2020-06-14T21:00:48.3954451Z ##[debug]INPUT_SERVERNAME: '88.198.44.249'
2020-06-14T21:00:48.3990602Z ##[debug]INPUT_DATABASENAME: 'Stage.TimeService'
2020-06-14T21:00:48.4026165Z ##[debug]INPUT_AUTHSCHEME: 'sqlServerAuthentication'
2020-06-14T21:00:48.4050818Z ##[debug]INPUT_SQLUSERNAME: 'Zoo-Director'
2020-06-14T21:00:48.4083226Z ##[debug]INPUT_SQLPASSWORD: 'Daniel#2019!newS'
2020-06-14T21:00:48.4112120Z ##[debug]INPUT_CONNECTIONSTRING (empty)
2020-06-14T21:00:48.4138318Z ##[debug]INPUT_PUBLISHPROFILE (empty)
2020-06-14T21:00:48.4172155Z ##[debug]INPUT_ADDITIONALARGUMENTS (empty)
2020-06-14T21:00:48.4205938Z ##[debug]INPUT_ADDITIONALARGUMENTSSQL (empty)
2020-06-14T21:00:48.4240088Z ##[debug]Loading module from path 'D:\a\_tasks\SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroup_4b506f7f-720f-47bb-bf21-029bac6a690d\0.3.23\ps_modules\TaskModuleSqlUtility\TaskModuleSqlUtility.psd1'.
2020-06-14T21:00:48.4269587Z ##[debug]Loading module from path 'D:\a\_tasks\SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroup_4b506f7f-720f-47bb-bf21-029bac6a690d\0.3.23\ps_modules\TaskModuleSqlUtility\TaskModuleSqlUtility.psm1'.
2020-06-14T21:00:48.4423108Z ##[debug]NonInteractive: False
2020-06-14T21:00:48.6017509Z ##[debug]Exporting function 'Invoke-DacpacDeployment'.
2020-06-14T21:00:48.6044940Z ##[debug]Exporting function 'Invoke-SqlQueryDeployment'.
2020-06-14T21:00:48.6091408Z ##[debug]Adding exceptions types.
2020-06-14T21:00:50.8081584Z ##[debug]Importing function 'Invoke-DacpacDeployment'.
2020-06-14T21:00:50.8099297Z ##[debug]Importing function 'Invoke-SqlQueryDeployment'.
2020-06-14T21:00:50.8847884Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[telemetry.publish area=SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroup;feature=SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroup]{"serverName": "56531c73afc443fce9712faf6ea6473e2b28f77562757d20dc806bf6549c3b0e","databaseName": "a44f4ee78fc10bbef97ea36bc9819a0a47d0e11f6a0aa5cedd395548086fa4e5"}
2020-06-14T21:00:50.9277590Z ##[debug]Finding files with pattern D:\a\r1\a/drop/migrations/TimeServiceDataContext.sql
2020-06-14T21:00:50.9331163Z ##[debug]Entering Find-VstsFiles.
2020-06-14T21:00:50.9388734Z ##[debug] LegacyPattern: 'D:\a\r1\a/drop/migrations/TimeServiceDataContext.sql'
2020-06-14T21:00:50.9831065Z ##[debug]Entering Get-MatchingItems.
2020-06-14T21:00:50.9873935Z ##[debug] IncludePatterns: 'D:\a\r1\a/drop/migrations/TimeServiceDataContext.sql'
2020-06-14T21:00:50.9931616Z ##[debug] ExcludePatterns: ''
2020-06-14T21:00:50.9981552Z ##[debug] IncludeFiles: 'True'
2020-06-14T21:00:51.0003180Z ##[debug] IncludeDirectories: 'False'
2020-06-14T21:00:51.0031742Z ##[debug] Force: 'False'
2020-06-14T21:00:51.2179973Z ##[debug]No paths.
2020-06-14T21:00:51.2213869Z ##[debug]Leaving Get-MatchingItems.
2020-06-14T21:00:51.2233073Z ##[debug]Total found: 0
2020-06-14T21:00:51.2257660Z ##[debug]Leaving Find-VstsFiles.
2020-06-14T21:00:51.2275406Z ##[debug]Matched files = 
2020-06-14T21:00:51.3304392Z ##[debug]Write-Exception error:
2020-06-14T21:00:51.3348086Z ##[debug]No files were found to deploy with search pattern D:\a\r1\a/drop/migrations/TimeServiceDataContext.sql
2020-06-14T21:00:51.3538650Z ##[debug]Caught exception from task script.
2020-06-14T21:00:51.3575755Z ##[debug]Error record:
2020-06-14T21:00:51.4275609Z ##[debug]No files were found to deploy with search pattern D:\a\r1\a/drop/migrations/TimeServiceDataContext.sql
2020-06-14T21:00:51.4293155Z ##[debug]At D:\a\_tasks\SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroup_4b506f7f-720f-47bb-bf21-029bac6a690d\0.3.23\Main.ps1:51 char:13
2020-06-14T21:00:51.4294350Z ##[debug]+             throw (Get-VstsLocString -Key "Nofileswerefoundtodeploywi ...
2020-06-14T21:00:51.4295348Z ##[debug]+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2020-06-14T21:00:51.4307202Z ##[debug]    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (No files were f...DataContext.sql:String) [], RuntimeException
2020-06-14T21:00:51.4319906Z ##[debug]    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : No files were found to deploy with search pattern D:\a\r1\a/drop/migrations/TimeServiceD    ataContext.sql
2020-06-14T21:00:51.4330337Z ##[debug] 
2020-06-14T21:00:51.4356258Z ##[debug]Script stack trace:
2020-06-14T21:00:51.4395383Z ##[debug]at Get-SingleFile, D:\a\_tasks\SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroup_4b506f7f-720f-47bb-bf21-029bac6a690d\0.3.23\Main.ps1: line 51
2020-06-14T21:00:51.4407230Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, D:\a\_tasks\SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroup_4b506f7f-720f-47bb-bf21-029bac6a690d\0.3.23\Main.ps1: line 175
2020-06-14T21:00:51.4422508Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
2020-06-14T21:00:51.4440151Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 22
2020-06-14T21:00:51.4454203Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 18
2020-06-14T21:00:51.4478858Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
2020-06-14T21:00:51.4497567Z ##[debug]Exception:
2020-06-14T21:00:51.4549822Z ##[debug]System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: No files were found to deploy with search pattern D:\a\r1\a/drop/migrations/TimeServiceDataContext.sql
2020-06-14T21:00:51.4853912Z ##[error]No files were found to deploy with search pattern D:\a\r1\a/drop/migrations/TimeServiceDataContext.sql
2020-06-14T21:00:51.4865099Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error]No files were found to deploy with search pattern D:\a\r1\a/drop/migrations/TimeServiceDataContext.sql
2020-06-14T21:00:51.4867288Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed]
2020-06-14T21:00:51.5269963Z ##[section]Finishing: Deploy using : sqlQuery
```

Comment: Have you try to execute the pipeline using the Debug flag and see the available paths?

Comment: Actually not, but let me add the debug output

Comment: The location where the artifacts are restored includes the name you gave it: `D:\a\r1\a\**ATRIFACTNAME**\drop\migrations\TimeServiceDataContext.sql`

Comment: What happens if you change the slash characters, /, to backslash characters, \?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Nothing changes when using a backslash. @ jesshouwing Even using the ArtifactName does not result in success, still the same error

Comment: Hi @Daniel DirtyNative Martin any update on this? Did you get a chance to implement the solution that I suggested, were you able to resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OP updated:**

Running the tasks on **his self hosted machine**  finally solved the issue.

---

> (Required) Location of the SQL file on the target. Provide semi-colon
> separated list of SQL script files to execute multiple files. The SQL
> scripts will be executed in the order given. Location can also be a
> UNC path like, \BudgetIT\Web\Deploy\FabrikamDB.sql. The UNC path
> should be accessible to the machine's administrator account.
> Environment variables are also supported, such as $env:windir,
> $env:systemroot, $env:windir\FabrikamFibre\DB. Wildcards can be used.
> For example, /*.sql for sql file present in all sub folders
>
> [*Source Link*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/sql-dacpac-deployment-on-machine-group?view=azure-devops)

You should use "\". Normally, the path will be something like below:

```
 $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\[Artifact name]\migrations\TimeServiceDataContext.sql
```

If you are using default drop name it will directly be

```
D:\a\r1\a\migrations\TimeServiceDataContext.sql
```

Besides, seems you are using self-host agent, you could also directly remote to the machine which host build agent and check the valid folder path.

Comment: Running the Pipeline on my own windows machine solved the issue. I don't know why, maybe someone knows more about this

Comment: Hi @DanielDirtyNativeMartin Glad to hear the issue solved. When we build or deploy our code in pipeline. We'd better to make sure the build/release agents are as same as our local environment. This will help to narrow down the issue. In your scenario, there are multiple reasons. For example, that may related to your build service account permission. Cause your build service account may lack permission on server, but it has corresponding permission on your own windows machine.

Comment: But how do I get permissions on a azure hosted machine?

Comment: Hi @DanielDirtyNativeMartin Sorry, you can't. But Microsoft-hosted agent pool will not work for you with every scenarios. For many teams this is the simplest way to run your jobs. You can try it first and see if it works for your build or deployment. If not, you can use a self-hosted agent. Self-hosted agents give you more control for your builds and deployments. That's why we provide both solutions.

Comment: Okay i see, so running the tasks on my self hosted machine solved my issue. If you want, you can edit you answer a little to provide the correct answer, I will accept it :)